# chart.js: line graph with 2 datasets of different lenght

Tags: chart.js

I just can't find a solution to what seems a easy problem to solve.

I have a dynamic line graph built with chart.js and based on data retrieved from a DB. User choices affect how data is picked. The graph makes a comparison between two datasets. the datasets can be of different lenght.
Let's say: dataset A can have 4 values, dataset B can have 8.

What I get is that if A dataset is longer, B dataset is shown as a line shorter than the line based on A dataset. But if the situation is the opposite, so A dataset is shorter than B dataset, B line is truncated to the lenght of A dataset so the existing values for B line are not shown.

Is there a way to prevent this and so adapt the size of the graph to the longer dataset, not the first one?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?